# 404 /phpmyadmin with Nginx and Debian 8 jessie

Tags: nginx, debian

I found lots of answers, but none solved my problem:

I try to access /phpmyadmin but I land on a 404 with Nginx 1.6.2, PHP7.0 and Debian 8 (Jessie).

This is my /etc/nginx/site-available/guillaume-rz.fr:

```
server {                                                                                 
    listen 80;                                                                       
    root /home/guillaume-rz/www;                                                     
    server_name www.guillaume-rz.fr;                                                 
    location / {                                                                     
            index index.php;                                                         
    }                                                                                

    location /phpmyadmin {                                                           
            root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;                                              
            index index.php index.html index.htm;                                    
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {                                     
                    try_files $uri =404;                                             
                    root /usr/share/;                                                
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock; # or 127.0.0.1:9000  
                    fastcgi_index index.php;                                         
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                               
            }                                                                        

            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$
                    root /usr/share/;                                                
            }                                                                        
    }                                                                                

    location /phpMyAdmin {                                                           
             rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;                                           
    }                                                                                

    location ~ \.php$ {                                                              
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;                                       
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;                          
            # include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                                     
            # fastcgi_index index.php;                                               
    }                                                                                
}
```

I install PhpMyAdmin, it is available here : /var/www/phpmyadmin/

And I create a symbolic link on : ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you share any log from ngnix? I'm not sure but I think that you are not pointing to the right root... Try changing `root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;`  to `root  /var/www/phpmyadmin/;`

Comment: No, it is not working with `root /var/www/phpmyadmin/;`I check the logs from /var/log/nginx/access.log but nothing about that. Same for error.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your PHP scripts are being processed by the last `location` block, even if they begin with `/phpmyadmin/`. The regular expression `location` block takes precedence over the prefix `location` block at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Use the `^~` modifier to change the precedence order, for example:

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {                                                           
    root /usr/share;                                              
    index index.php index.html index.htm;                                    

    location ~ \.php$ {                                     
        try_files $uri =404;                                             
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock; # or 127.0.0.1:9000  

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                               
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }                                                                            
}
```